# Issue with Subprocess Popen Python

Tags: python, input, parameters, subprocess, popen

I searched on stack overflow but I did'nt find a correct answer.

I use subprocess popen to call and run an entire python script and it works fine, like that :

`subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/home/pc/Dossier/Dossier2/Nom.py'], )`

But in my system I want to modify a variable in the script Nom.py when I call it with subprocess popen. I heard about inputs parameters for subprcess popen. Do you think that is possible and do you have any examples ?

Thanks for your future answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much better way to call Python code from within Python, and it's to... call Python code from within Python :)

In other words, make sure that `Nom.py` [can be imported without side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) and has a main function that you can call, and then simply import it and call the function.

---

But if, for whatever reason, you must do it through `subprocess`, you can add command line arguments after the name of the script:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/home/pc/Dossier/Dossier2/Nom.py', 'some_value'], )
```

These arguments can be accessed (as strings) in the called script through `sys.argv`.

Comment: Exactly ! thank you, that was I looked for regarding sys.argv, I will investigate this part and I will priorize the classic way with Nom.py. Thanks! I'm going to try it